# Verify date with SQL / PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am having trouble verifying dates in my code. It's not quite working how it should.

The parts that are wrong have to do with this.

```
ADD_COMPLEX_SALE_TO_DB - GENERATED UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION
ADD_COMPLEX_SALE_TO_DB - DATE NOT VALID EXCEPTION INCORRECT (WRONG MONTH)
ADD_COMPLEX_SALE_TO_DB - DATE NOT VALID EXCEPTION INCORRECT (WRONG DAY)
```

My code for testing is this. I have a different block for outputting which has no issues.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_COMPLEX_SALE_TO_DB (pcustid Number, pprodid Number, pqty Number, pdate Varchar2) AS
    QTY_OUTSIDE_RANGE EXCEPTION;
    STATUS_NOT_OK EXCEPTION;
    INVALID_SALE_DATE EXCEPTION;
    vCUST CUSTOMER%ROWTYPE;
    vPROD PRODUCT%ROWTYPE;
    SALEID SALE%ROWTYPE;
    vPROD_ERROR INT := 0;
BEGIN
    IF 1 > pqty OR pqty > 999 THEN
    RAISE QTY_OUTSIDE_RANGE;
    END IF;
    
    SELECT * INTO vCUST
    FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE CUSTID = pcustid;
    
    vPROD_ERROR := 1; 
    
    IF vCUST.STATUS != 'OK' THEN
    RAISE STATUS_NOT_OK;
    END IF; 

    SELECT * INTO vPROD
    FROM PRODUCT
    WHERE PRODID = pprodid;
    
    IF (LENGTH(pdate) <> 8) THEN 
        RAISE INVALID_SALE_DATE;
    END IF;
    
    INSERT INTO SALE (SALEID, CUSTID, PRODID, QTY, PRICE, SALEDATE) 
    VALUES (SALE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, pcustid, pprodid, pqty, vPROD.SELLING_PRICE, pdate); 
        
    UPD_CUST_SALESYTD_IN_DB(pcustid, (pqty*vPROD.SELLING_PRICE));   
    UPD_PROD_SALESYTD_IN_DB(pprodid, (pqty*vPROD.SELLING_PRICE));

EXCEPTION
    WHEN QTY_OUTSIDE_RANGE THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20234, 'Sale Quantity outside valid range');
    WHEN STATUS_NOT_OK THEN 
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20245, 'Customer status is not OK');
    WHEN INVALID_SALE_DATE THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20252, 'Date not valid');
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        IF vPROD_ERROR = 0 THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20263, 'Customer ID not found');
        ELSE 
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20271, 'Product ID not found');
        END IF;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, SQLERRM);
END;
```

Here are the table creation statements.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CUSTID  NUMBER
, CUSTNAME  VARCHAR2(100)
, SALES_YTD NUMBER
, STATUS    VARCHAR2(7)
, PRIMARY KEY   (CUSTID) 
);
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
PRODID  NUMBER
, PRODNAME  VARCHAR2(100)
, SELLING_PRICE NUMBER
, SALES_YTD NUMBER
, PRIMARY KEY   (PRODID)
);
CREATE TABLE SALE (
SALEID  NUMBER
, CUSTID    NUMBER
, PRODID    NUMBER
, QTY   NUMBER
, PRICE NUMBER
, SALEDATE  DATE
, PRIMARY KEY   (SALEID)
, FOREIGN KEY   (CUSTID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER
, FOREIGN KEY   (PRODID) REFERENCES PRODUCT
);
```

How can I go about getting testing the date is valid? It appears I need to somehow break down and test the month/day/year separately but I am unsure about how best to do that.

Comment: Oracle has no exception "DATE NOT VALID EXCEPTION INCORRECT (WRONG MONTH)".  That appears to be an exception that you're raising.  But the code you posted doesn't raise such an exception so I'd guess there is some additional code you're not showing.  I'm not sure why `pDate` in your procedure is a `varchar2` rather than a `date`.  If you're going to take a `varchar2` parameter, you should be explicitly casting it to a `date` in your `insert` statement via a `to_date` with an explicit format mask that reflects the format of the string you're passing in.

Comment: The input for pDate in a varchar2 because of the way the date information is provided by the user,

Comment: The exception list at the top is a self-assessment we have been given to check if the code does what it's meant to. It's not an official oracle exception, just a practice marking.

Comment: To validate that a string can be converted a date, try converting it. What is your Oracle version? From 12.2 onwards you might look at [validate_conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html) and the `on conversion error` clause of [to_date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html).

Comment: By the way, `WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, SQLERRM);` does not add any value. If you didn't catch the exception, the default behaviour would be to fail the procedure and return an error stack with more information than your version does.

Comment: If you're going to take a `varchar2` parameter, you should be explicitly casting it to a date in your insert statement via a `to_date` with an explicit format mask that reflects the format of the string you're passing in.  Not knowing what format the string you expect the user to pass in, I can't suggest what format mask you should be using.

Comment: Its been given to me as a string to deal with within this procedure. We cannot change the type that is passed in. I see your point about the input statement and will adjust it now.

Comment: As for the `WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, SQLERRM);`  We were also given that to use as a final catch statment. We were given all the exception names and codes we need to use. 

My issue at the moment is it seems I am somehow meant to test date and month in the process of validating the date parameter

Comment: I am not fully sure which version or Oracle we are using, I am only aware its through SQL Developer

Comment: @StudentWork Various ways to check your database version: https://christian-gohmann.de/2020/02/27/different-ways-to-get-the-current-database-version/ (or just try `validate_conversion` etc and see if it's recognised).

Answer (score 1):

Don't check dates by checking it's length. 01/01/21 is a validate date but 99/01/21 is not. The oracle database will try to do an implicit conversion but it is not a good practice to change strings to dates.

Since you are getting a string, whoever is passing the data must know what *format* to pass the date in. If it is  february, 9 2021, will he pass 09/02/21, 02/09/21, 09-FEB-21 or 09-FEB-2021 ? All of those are valid dates so you should assume date the [format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-22F2B830-261E-4BF0-91FB-6A1DAFC6D0A3) of the incoming date argument is known. With the format known you can still get invalid dates. Suppose your date format is DD/MM/YY then 09/02/21 is a valid date but 50/02/21 isn't and 09/50/21 isn't either.

Use `TO_DATE` to convert the string to datatype `DATE`. Oracle has a couple of exceptions that are date related.

Example:

```
DECLARE
  l_date_input VARCHAR2(20) := '50/02/21';
  l_date DATE;
BEGIN
  l_date := TO_DATE(l_date_input,'DD/MM/YY');
END;
/
ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
ORA-06512: at line 5
01847. 00000 -  "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"
```

Try this yourself. Change '50/02/21' to '09/50/21' and see what exception is raised.

Now, let's put this together in an example that only handles the date part of the assignment. Note that this example is an anonymous pl/sql block but it can easily be changed to a procedure. The pragma `EXCEPTION_INIT` allows [association of a user-defined exception name with an error code](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/EXCEPTION_INIT-pragma.html#GUID-873A087E-A470-4798-9152-16BC673B4940) so the errors raised in the example below can be mapped to your own exceptions.

```
DECLARE
  l_date_input VARCHAR2(2000);
  l_date DATE;
  
  --exception thrown: ORA-01843: not a valid month
  e_not_a_valid_month EXCEPTION; 
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (e_not_a_valid_month, -01843); 
  --exception thrown:  ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
  e_not_a_valid_day EXCEPTION; 
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (e_not_a_valid_day, -01847);   

BEGIN
  l_date_input := '01/99/21';
  l_date :=  TO_DATE(l_date_input,'DD/MM/YY');
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN e_not_a_valid_month THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20234, 'DATE NOT VALID EXCEPTION INCORRECT (WRONG MONTH)');
  WHEN e_not_a_valid_day THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20235, 'DATE NOT VALID EXCEPTION INCORRECT (WRONG DAY)');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20236, 'GENERATED UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION');
END;
/
ORA-20234: DATE NOT VALID EXCEPTION INCORRECT (WRONG MONTH)
ORA-06512: at line 17
```